# What is the original reference for disorientations on tangle diagrams?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, virtual-knots

There are several invariants whose "natural" domain is a category of **disoriented** tangles, that is tangles which are piecewise-oriented, but which contain points called `disorientations' at which the orientation is reversed.

*For example*:

- Khovanov homology [HERE](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701339v2.pdf) and [HERE](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.3051.pdf).
- Kauffman's extended bracked polynomial [HERE](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2546.pdf).

I was unable, however, to track down the origin of the idea- where were disorientations first used, and what is the correct citation to use to reference it outside the context of one of these invariants?

Further, I would like to ask whether there are other known contexts in which disoriented tangles of some flavour appear, other than the contexts mentioned above.

Comment: Can you describe disoriented tangles by some universal property?

Comment: @Qiaochu: The free braided category with duals (spherical) generated by one anti-symmetrically self-dual object.  (Probably my braided category adjectives are not quite right.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *term* "disoriented tangle" first appeared in arxiv:0701339v2 (your first link).  That is also the earliest reference I know for bordisms of disoriented tangles.

But the *idea* of disoriented tangles is much older.  It emerges naturally when one considers string diagrams for $Rep(U_q sl_2)$.  See, for example, Figures 3.22 and 4.8 of Kirby and Melvin's paper [here](https://tqft.net/svn/d4/trunk/links-article/papers/kirby-melvin.pdf).  I strongly suspect there are earlier examples in papers of Reshetikhin and/or Kirillov and/or Turaev.